# Calling data from Javascript through a proxy server

Tags: php, javascript, api, post, google-chrome-extension

We have the following code in Javascript:

```
var speakMe = function (text) {
        var key, lang, url, audio;
        key = "key=1234567890";
        lang = "sv_se";
        url = "http://api.ttsengine.com/api/read?" + key + "&lang=en_us&voice=male1&speed=100&audioformat=ogg&oggbitrate=100&text=" + text; 
        audio = new Audio(url);
        audio.play();
    };
```

It functions well. However, I would like to mask the key. For this I have been advised to use a PHP proxy script.

I found [this proxy](https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy/blob/master/ba-simple-proxy.php) but I don't know how to implement it. How do I get the data I normally get, but through this proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation of your proxy script. you can call your script and pass a `url` argument which then it will return the content back. you must also set `mode=native` as another url parameter.

```
// > ba-simple-proxy.php?url=http://example.com/&mode=native
// 
// Response:
// 
// > <html>...</html>
// 
// Topic: Notes
// 
// * Assumes magic_quotes_gpc = Off in php.ini
```